# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. How should we solve it?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, api

I want to use JSONP.

I have encountered this error when writing code like this:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>   Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

What is the problem?

```
function getAirLine(from , to , date) {

var href = "https://api.flightstats.com/flex/schedules/rest/v1/json/from/"+from+"/to/"+to+"/departing/"+date+"?appId=[myKey1]&appKey=[myKey2]&extendedOptions=languageCode:ko";
$.ajax({
        url : href,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success : function(datas) {
            console.log(datas);
            var dataSet = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < datas.scheduledFlights.length; i++) {
                for(var j = 0 ; j < datas.appendix.airlines.length ; j++){
                    if(datas.scheduledFlights[i].carrierFsCode == datas.appendix.airlines[j].fs){
                        airlines = datas.appendix.airlines[j].name;
                    }
                } 
                var dataArr = [];
                dataArr.push(datas.scheduledFlights[i].departureAirportFsCode);
                dataArr.push(datas.scheduledFlights[i].departureTime.substring(11,16))
                dataArr.push(datas.scheduledFlights[i].arrivalAirportFsCode)
                dataArr.push(datas.scheduledFlights[i].arrivalTime.substring(11,16))
                dataArr.push(datas.scheduledFlights[i].carrierFsCode + datas.scheduledFlights[i].flightNumber)
                dataArr.push(airlines);
                dataSet.push(dataArr);
            }
            console.log(dataSet);
            $('#realTime').DataTable({
                destroy: true,
                data: dataSet,
                columns: [
                    { title: "From" },
                    { title: "Depart.Time" },
                    { title: "To" },
                    { title: "Arrial.Time" },
                    { title: "AirLine" },
                    { title: "AirCode" }
                ]
            });                 
        },
        error: function(datas) {
              console.log('실패 - ', datas);
            }
    });
}
```

How should we solve it?

Comment: I'm surprised you get a CORS error when you request JSONP - that makes no sense, because JSONP can never result in a CORS error.

Comment: the last time you posted this code you claimed yo be getting a syntax error - what have you changed?

Comment: Cross-origin requests require agreement from the remote server, by it actively supporting either JSON-P (involving a modified response) or CORS (involving modified headers). If the API you're trying to reach doesn't offer these, the request won't be able to made directly from the client.

Comment: your opening statement `I want to use jsonp` suggests you didn't understand the comments in your previous questions. JSONP is something that the server has to support. JSONP is not how you get around CORS because you want to, JSONP is how an API offers to help you get around CORS because they don't know how or don't want to enable CORS but still want to allow connections from a client. The simplest solution is to *proxy* the request via *your* server, thus avoiding CORS, and using the API as it was meant to be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable CORS in header, in some Language like PHP, JAVA, C# etc
example in php

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');
```

or only with JS. Idk how but it works :D
Its a method with https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/
example

```
const CORS = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const endpoint = CORS + "https://api.deezer.com/playlist/3314523926/tracks";
```

*I have an example* in codepen https://codepen.io/rogergcc/pen/wyggGX

Comment: I don't think the OP owns `flightstats.com` domain, so enabling CORS is not an option

Comment: cors-anywhere works by being a proxy for the actual request and having CORS response headers in the response - this can work, but depending on the API, may have limited success - I know any API I write that does not allow CORS would also prevent such shenanigans - if I don't want my API accessible  directly through client, I would actively prevent it